# knife ssh contains sudo and prompts for password

Tags: chef-infra, sudo, knife

I am using a execute resource which calls knife ssh. The only issue is, it works fine if sudo isn't used, the moment sudo is introduced password for root is requested and the cookbook doesn't converge. Need help:

**Current State**:

```
...    
execute 'command' do
           command "knife ssh 'name:mynode' -x user123 -i '/tmp/user123.pem' -a ipaddress 'sudo echo Hi > /tmp/output.txt;'"
            live_stream true
end
...
```

After chef-client is run (as a Jenkins Build) it prompts the following and doesn't converge because the password is not put-in:
mynode> knife sudo password:

**Desired State**:

```
...    
execute 'command' do
               command "knife ssh 'name:mynode' -x user123 -i '/tmp/user123.pem' -a ipaddress 'sudo echo Hi > /tmp/output.txt;'"
                live_stream true
end
...
```

After chef-client is run, string `Hi` is stored in `/tmp/output.txt`

**NOTE:**
If ***sudo*** is excluded, then the convergence takes place. Is it a way wherein we can include `sudo` and still attain convergence without having to input the password.

Comment: Why are you using Chef recipe code to call `knife ssh`? That's a really weird thing to do.

Comment: @coderanger  Once a Jenkins build is initiated this chef recipe will run the `execute` resource block. Is that a bad practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to create / use another user and to generate an SSH key pair for that user to use. Then if you require root privileges you could just give the user the privileges required.